# alertdialog setItems with custom layout

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When I use setItems with custom layout, my layout is shown below the item buttons (created by setItems).

Is there any way I can show custom layout on top, and then the item buttons? Or I need to add the item buttons in my custom layout?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_addons, null);
    myDialog.setTitle(title);

    myDialog.setView(layout); // WANT TO SHOW THIS ON TOP

    //THEN THIS
    myDialog.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //DO SOMTHING
        }
    });
    myDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    myDialog.create().show();
```